# Scope leaking before private function is returned

Tags: javascript, binding, scope

I am learning binding in javascript and have testing code as followings

```
    var text = "Global Text";

    var FooObj = {
        text: "Foo text",
        GetText: function () {
            return this.text;
        }
    };

    function BarObject() {
        var text = "Private Bar Text";
        var BarGetText = FooObj.GetText;
        alert(f());
        return {
            text: "Public Bar Text",
            GetText: BarGetText,
            f: f
        }
        function f() {
            var text = "Bar f() text";
            var t = BarGetText();
            return t;
        }
    }

    var obj = BarObject(); // Global Text is alerted
    alert(obj.GetText()); //Public Bar Text Text is alerted
    alert(obj.f()); // Global Text is alerted
```

As f() being called in obj's initiation, I expect "Private Bar Text" is referred when this.text is referred in FooObj. Quite strangely text in global scope is called which is unrelated to FooObj and BarObject. Anyone can explain why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is how scope is applied depending on how the function is actually called. You should reference the [MDN page for `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#Function_context):

> Inside a function, the value of this depends on how the function is called.

```
function f1(){
    return this;
}

f1() === window; // global object
```

The reason `this` references `window` in the `f()` call in the constructor is due to it being a naked call. The difference of the two latter calls is essentially the same. The value of `t` will always be the global text, because the call to `BarGetText` is a "simple call", it will not change no matter how many objects and scopes you pass it around through.

Comment: Is there a way to ask FooObj take BarObject's private variables without exposing them to the public?

Comment: Sorry, I think I got the solution. 
Thanks for answering